# Responsive Social Buttons

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 4 social buttons in a row at the top of my web page.

```
HTML Code
    <div id="social-buttons">
      <span id="facebook-like">
        <!-- FACEBOOK LIKE - START -->
          <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/romancestuck" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" ref="like_button"></div>
        <!-- FACEBOOK LIKE - END -->
      </span>
      <span id="twitter">
        <!-- TWITTER FOLLOW - START -->
          <a href="https://twitter.com/RomanceStuck" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="true" data-width="150px" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow </a>
          <script>
            !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
          </script>
        <!-- TWITTER FOLLOW - END -->
      </span>
      <span id="pinterest">
        <!-- PINTEREST.COM - START -->
          <a data-pin-do="buttonFollow" href="http://www.pinterest.com/romancestuck/">RomanceStuck.com</a>
        <!-- PINTEREST.COM - END -->
      </span>
      <span id="google-plus">
        <!-- PLUS.GOOGLE.COM BADGE - START -->
          <div class="g-follow" data-annotation="bubble" data-height="20" data-href="//plus.google.com/106310759116433212593" data-rel="publisher"></div>
        <!-- PLUS.GOOGLE.COM BADGE - END -->
        <!-- PLUS.GOOGLE.COM WIDGET ASYNCHRONOUS JAVASCRIPT LOADER (PLACE THIS TAG AFTER THE LAST GOOGLE PLUS WIDGET) - START -->
          <script>
            (function(){
              var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
              po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
              var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
            })();
          </script>
        <!-- PLUS.GOOGLE.COM WIDGET ASYNCHRONOUS JAVASCRIPT LOADER (PLACE THIS TAG AFTER THE LAST GOOGLE PLUS WIDGET) - END -->
      </span>
    </div>

CSS Code
  */* CSS CODE FOR ALL DEVICES - START */
      #social-buttons
      {
        clear:both;
      }
      #social-buttons > span > *
      {
        vertical-align:middle !important;
      }  
      #facebook-like
      {
        padding:0 13px 0 0;
      }
      #twitter
      {
      }
      #pinterest
      {
        padding:0 17px 0 0;
      }
      #google-plus
      {
      }
  /* CSS CODE FOR ALL DEVICES - END */

  /* CSS CODE ONLY FOR MOBILE DEVICES - START */
    @media screen and (max-width:727px)
    {
        #google-plus
        {
          display:none;
        }
        #twitter
        {
          display:none;
        }
    }
  /* CSS CODE ONLY FOR MOBILE DEVICES - END */*
```

Right now I am hiding the Google Plus and Twitter social buttons on mobile devices because they don't wrap right on the smaller screen and instead mess up the width of the page. How can I get these social buttons to wrap right and take 2 lines on mobile devices?

Thanks!

Comment: In your media query, change `display:none` to `display:block`. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5nab9x2/).

Comment: For mobile, I would like 2 lines of social buttons with 2 buttons on each line.

Comment: One option is to change the HTML structure so that each "row" element contains two buttons. Then set the rows to `inline-block` for desktop and `block` for mobile (or use floats, if you prefer). Incidentally, you may want to include *all* of your requirements in your question itself (use the "edit" link).

Comment: I don't know if it is a requirement. I just thought it would look better and it is what I meant by wrap right. Putting every button on its own line isn't really wrapping the buttons.

Comment: You mean "float" or "align" to the right side of the screen? "Wrapping" generally refers to text wrapping around another element or to the way lines are broken in a block of text (i.e. wrapping to the next line).

Comment: Is there a way to set it as a block of text and have it wrap so it fits the mobile display resolution?

Answer (score -1):

You can have 3 or 2 diffrent set of style (or one style only ofcourse!) by wrapping your styles in `@media only screen and (min-width: XXXpx) {` and ofcourse a `}` for example:

```
/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) { 
a { 
   color:#0F0;
}
}
/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
a { 
   color:#00F;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question. The OP is already using a media query and colors don't affect wrapping.